# Clients are unable to receive my emails

Tags: email

I am getting following message after sending email to my client's official email address:

```
Subject: Delivery Status Notification (Delay)

This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification

THIS IS A WARNING MESSAGE ONLY.

YOU DO NOT NEED TO RESEND YOUR MESSAGE.

Delivery to the following recipient has been delayed:

     Nominika.ZXleksy@XYZ.ie

Message will be retried for 2 more day(s)

Technical details of temporary failure: 
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain kentech.ie by mx.kentech.ie. [91.103.2.154].
```

The error that the other server returned was:

```
554-Service unavailable; Client host [mail-pf0-f169.google.com] blocked using 554-Barracuda Reputation;
554 http://www.barracudanetworks.com/reputation/?r=1&ip=182.69.185.110
```

Its happening very frequently.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please re-read the page you linked though. The reason why this happens are mentioned there.

Answer (score 0):

#### Its happening very frequently.

From the page you [linked](http://www.barracudacentral.org/reputation?r=1&ip=182.69.185.110) to:

> **Sorry, your email was blocked**
>
> We are sorry you have reached this page because an email was blocked
>   based on its originating IP address having a "poor" reputation. The
>   "poor" reputation may have been caused by one of the following
>   reasons:
>
> - Your email server contains a virus and has been sending out spam.
> - Your email server may be misconfigured.
> - Your PC may be infected with a virus or botnet software program.
> - Someone in your organization may have a PC infected with a virus or botnet program.
> - You may be utilizing a dynamic IP address which was previously utilized by a known spammer.
> - Your marketing department may be sending out bulk emails that do not comply with the CAN-SPAM Act.
> - You may have an insecure wireless network which is allowing unknown users to use your network to send spam.
> - In some rare cases, your recipient's Barracuda Spam Firewall may be misconfigured.

That page also contains a "Look IP Reputation" button.

Click on it and you will get:

> The IP address 182.69.185.110 is listed as "poor" on the Barracuda Reputation System. To request removal, please [click here](http://www.barracudacentral.org/rbl/removal-request/182.69.185.110).